# python: module has no attribute mechanize

Tags: python, attributes, module, mechanize-python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import mechanize

mech = mechanize.Browser()
page = br.open(SchoolRank('KY'))
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mechanize.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mechanize
  File "/home/jcress/Documents/programming/schooldig/trunk/mechanize.py", line 12, in <module>
    mech = mechanize.Browser()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Browser'
```

And I'm confused.  I have the module installed for 2.6 and 2.7, same result...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your filename away from mechanize.py.  Python is importing *your* file as the module.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was was still stuck until I realised that I had to delete the corresponding .pyc  file