# unable to import browser from mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am using mechanize for the first time. If I type the line `from mechanize import Browser`in python shell (interpreter) it doesn't give any error but when run the same code as a part of  a .py file it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/namit/Codes/BS4/mechanize.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mechanize
  File "/home/namit/Codes/BS4/mechanize.py", line 4, in <module>
    mech = mechanize.Browser()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Browser'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: module has no attribute mechanize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236365/python-module-has-no-attribute-mechanize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your filename from mechanize.py. Python is importing your file as the module, instead of importing the mechanize library.

Comment: May I ask the reason for the downvote? This is the proper answer

Answer (score 1):

Rename your filename to something other than mechanize.py

Giving files names same as that of the modules imported causes the file to be imported instead of the intended module.